# Assign new value to item in array if it matches another item without looping

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm needing to apply a conditional statement to every iteration of an array of object items without using for loops or any kind of loop that involves defining an index variable. Can this be achieved some how with map or filter?

Here is an example including a for loop.

```
const objectArray = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}] 
let currentKey = 3

for(i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++) {
    if(objectArray[i].key === currentKey) {
       objectArray[i].key = 0
       }
}
```

```
> console.log(objectArray)
[{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 0}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}]
```

How can I achieve this without a for loop.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "index based loop"? Both `Array#map` and `Array#filter` can use the index if need be. Did you already try anything? Using `Array#map` should be straightforward.

Comment: Index based loop meaning you have to manually define an index variable as is the case with for loops. I have to avoid defining an index variable. Perhaps I don't quite understand map well enough, from what I understand, if I tried something like `objectArray.map(item => {item.key === currentKey}` I can't figure out how to then say, assign the item found to be true in that condition to 0 as is seen in my example. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `map` and `filter` will be an elegant solution:

```js
const objectArray = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}] 
let currentKey = 3

objectArray.filter((e) => e.key === currentKey).map((e) => e.key = 0);

console.log(objectArray)
```

Comment: @srb633 why do you want to avoid the loop? You could use a `for..of` loop as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935732/3082296). This solution loops the the array twice.

Comment: Trying to use it in combination with jsx which I have very little experience with. I'm sure it's possible to use a for loop in jsx, but i'd prefer to take this route for the time being, works great. Thank you.

Comment: @adiga you right, for..of loops only once, while this loop once the full array and once the filtered. If the array is not extremely big that efficiency become a thing, i would stick to my solution, it's cleaner and more understandable in a functionality pow

Answer (score 2):

If modifying the existing array is ok (i.e. inplace), you can simply do this using [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const objectArray = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}]
let currentKey = 3


function replaceKey(arr, keyId, replacmentId) {
    const element = arr.find(element => element.key === keyId);
    if(element) {
        element.key = replacmentId;
    }
}

replaceKey(objectArray, currentKey, 0);
console.log(objectArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. This can transform the object and return it.

If you are not afraid of possible memory tweaks or object values that are reassigned, you can use:

```js
const objectArray = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}] 
const currentKey = 3
const result = objectArray.map((item)=>{
  if(item.key === currentKey)
    item.key = 0;
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

But if you don't want to risk memory tweaks, you should use:

```js
const objectArray = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}] 
const currentKey = 3
const result = [...objectArray.map((item)=>{
  const newItem = {...item}
  if(newItem.key === currentKey)
    newItem.key = 0;
  return newItem;
})];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
objectArray.forEach((x) => x.key === currentKey && (x.key = 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
const objectArray = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}] 
let currentKey = 3
for (el of objectArray) {
  if (el.key === currentKey) {
    el.key = 0;
  }
}
console.log(objectArray);
```

this doesn't require mentioning/using [i]ndex var

> It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.